# NodeJS - Why npm does not share dependencies?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

Even I build package.json and run

<kbd>npm install ./</kbd>

npm install dependencies of dependencies even it's perfectly equal.

Ex) 
ExpressJs 4.0.0-rc4 node_modules/cookie === cookie-parser node_modules/cookie

When nodeJs load file, it's cached per file.
So, if npm does not share dependencies, same module can be parsed several time and use much more memory.

Comment: See if [`npm dedupe`](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-dedupe.html) helps things in your project, but I understand your point. You can read some of their rationale/rationalizations for this on their [faq](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-faq.html) and about their preferred [install approach](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is for project maintenance and consistent (and simple) usage. Now each package is perfectly independent of the others, and each package adheres to its own `package.json` file.

If one package updates its dependencies, NPM simply has to check that package. If it were sharing a reference, it would not only need to update the new version for the one that changed, but also switch and re-reference the old version for the other package. Or if a package was deleted that shared a reference, NPM would need to re-check **all other packages** to see if another was still using it. And other odd use cases when sharing.

Storage is cheap these days and most NPM modules are small in (file) size. Ease of maintenance and consistent updating is worth more than saving a few MBs of files.

Comment: I do not think the npm modules are small in size. If a project depends a lot of library, it would use a lot of time to copy the whole set of library into a folder. For me, it is quite troublesome as I waste a lot time and storage for a project which is just for testing propose.